# How to add default constatint in query dynamically in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I am writing one query in that I am doing sum of the two column.
some time it is happening that "amount" column  is null so It returns null to me.

But I want if my amount column is null then I want it to be zero.

Note :-- I cannot add default constraint to the table in which amount column is present Bcoz first time when I calculate the sum data is not present in that table.

so I want to add default constraint to that column dynamically

How to achieve that.

Here's My Query.

```
select 
sum((ism.selling_price * som.quantity) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * som.quantity))/100))) as Amnt,
(sum((ism.selling_price * som.quantity) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * som.quantity))/100))) - sum(amount)) as total,
sm.sell_order_no, 
r.retailer_id,
r.business_name 
from RS_Sell_Order_Master as SM 
left outer join RS_Sell_Order_Mapping as SOM on SOM.sell_order_no = sm.sell_order_no 
left outer join RS_Receipt_Master as RM on rm.sales_order = sm.sell_order_no 
left outer join RS_Relationship_Master as R on r.retailer_id = sm.retailer_id
left outer join RS_Inventory_Master as Im on im.product_id = som.product_id
left outer join RS_Inventory_Selling_Master as Ism on ism.product_code = im.product_code
left outer join RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master as SIIM on siim.selling_product_id = ism.selling_product_id
left outer join RS_Tax_Master as tm on tm.tax_id = siim.tax_id
where r.retailer_id = 24
group by sm.sell_order_no,r.retailer_id,r.business_name
having (sum((ism.selling_price * som.quantity) + (((tm.tax_amount*(ism.selling_price * som.quantity))/100))) - sum(amount)) > 0
```

Comment: I have reverted your edit; please do not change the entire nature of a question, as that renders any answers and comments incorrect. If you have a second question: *ask a second question*

Comment: but can you please tell me how to use sub query for this please

Comment: That is not a clear question; to use a sub-query, you simply write a sub-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isnull`, i.e.:

```
...sum(isnull(amount,0))...
```

other useful related functions here are `nullif` and `coalesce`

Comment: yes, you can read about it at in this post on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

Comment: thnk you very much for your valuable time Mr. Mark. I appricaite your efforts. It works

Comment: hey can you help me for the same query but for sub query error

Answer (score 1):

This will give you 0 if is null then.

```
ISNULL(SUM(COLUMN),0)
```